# Eight points in a fixed circle

Tags: geometry

In the below figure, the point $P$ is inside the ellipse, $A, B, C, D$ are points on the ellipse, and segment $AB$ is perpendicular and intersects with segment $CD$ at $P$. The line $PE$ is perpendicular and intersects with segment $AC$ at $E$, and the line $PE$ intersects with the opposite segment $BD$ at $F$. The line $PG$ is perpendicular and intersects with segment $AD$ at $G$, and the line $PG$ intersects with the opposite segment $BC$ at $H$. The line $PI$ is perpendicular and intersects with segment $BD$ at $I$, and the line $PI$ intersects with the opposite segment $AC$ at $J$. The line $PK$ is perpendicular and intersects with segment $BC$ at $K$, and the line $PK$ intersects with the opposite segment $AD$ at $L$.

How to prove that the eight points $E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L$ are in the same circle and this circle's center and radius are only determined by point $P$'s position, in other words, the positions of $A, B, C, D$ don't influence this circle's center and radius. I have investigated this problem when the ellipse is converted to a circle, [wolfram mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eight-PointCircleTheorem.html) and [Eight points in a circle](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMT668.Folders.F97/Anderson/geometry/geometry1project/eightpointcircle/eightpointcircle.html), but I don't know whether it can help to solve the ellipse problem.

If the ellipse function is $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$, the coordinates of point $P$ is $(s, t)$ and guarantees $\frac{s^2}{a^2} + \frac{t^2}{b^2} < 1$, give this circle's equation.

[image: The figure of this problem]

Answer (score 4):

The proof can be found in Theorem 4 of [Josefsson, Martin (2012), "Characterizations of Orthodiagonal Quadrilaterals" (PDF), Forum Geometricorum, 12: 13–25](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2012volume12/FG201202.pdf), where it's referred to as the second eight point circle theorem.  It's too long to reproduce here, but the URL should be stable and [Forum Geometricorum](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/index1.html) is published online.  I don't think it addresses why the circle is independent of the positions of $A,B,C,D$, so this part of the question is still open.

The Wikipedia entry on [Orthodiagonal Quadrilaterals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodiagonal_quadrilateral#Characterizations) refers to this theorem.